# WPF: Ideas to set an flag enum value for a single object using Binding Mechanism

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, enums

I have a Enum for example...

```
    public enum TypeIdentifier {
            NotSet = 0,
            Type1= 1,
            Type2= 2,
            Type3= 3,
            Type4= 4,
            Type5= 5
        }

public class CommonObject
{

TypeIdentifier myTypeIdentifier {get; set;}
}
```

I have a WPF UserControl that has a generalized object binding.I have a common object that is used three times,masked as 5 different UserControls (member use varies).

I need to include hidden the value say TypeIdentifier.Type1 in UserControl One.How can I do this.I just need the object member to be set to TypeIdentifier.Type1 what ever control in the UserControl it is.The thing is that I can't directly reference the enum above in my user control project..:-( Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't reference the enum, then you'll have to use `int`s and [`Enum.Parse()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa328348.aspx), probably hidden in a [`ValueConverter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms771571.aspx).